# Como hacer para que no se me repitan los elementos de un RANDOM CON ELEMENTOS DE ARRAYLIST JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, random

En este caso cuando voy a imprimir los datos de productos he puesto un random en cantidad y precio porque cuando inicie el programa cada producto tenga unas cantidades diferentes y precios diferentes, el problema que tengo es que me lo hace aleatoriamente pero me repite los precios y las cantidades entonces no me lo hace bien,me tendria que hacer aleatoriamente las cantidad y los precios pero de los 8 productos y no repetirlos y no se como hacerlo! gracias, 
**el código que comento esta abajo del todo!**

```
package m3.uf5.ac02;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 *
 * @author Alumno
 */
public class M3UF5AC02 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */




       static Stack <Alumno> alumnos = new Stack <Alumno> ();
       static Stack <Profesor> profesores = new Stack <Profesor> ();
       static Stack <Persona> profalum = new Stack <Persona> ();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       ArrayList <Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();



       //Añadimos los datos a la arrayList 
       l.add(1);
       l.add(2);
       l.add(2);
       l.add(4);
       l.add(5);
       l.add(2);
       l.add(7);
       l.add(8);
       l.add(9);






       String f;

       System.out.println("1.- Eliminar Elemento de un ArrayList");
       System.out.println("2.- Datos a replazar en una pila");
       System.out.println("3.- Datos a replazar en una ArrayList");
       System.out.println("4.- Indica la posicion que quieres imprimir ");
       System.out.println("5.- Apilar los Profesor y los Alumnos en una misma pila");
       System.out.println("6.- Mostrar Productos y Sumar su Precio final");
       System.out.println("Indica la Intruccion a Realizar ");
       f = Scan.next();



       switch(f){

           case "1":
           borrarnum(l);

           break;

           case "2":

                remplazarpilas();


           case "3":
               mezcla();




           case "4":


               imprimeenteros();


           case "5":

               apilar();



           case "6":

               productos();

    }









    }

    public static void borrarnum(ArrayList <Integer> l){
       Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Indicame el Numero a Eliminar de el ArrayList");
       int n = Scan.nextInt();




       for(int i = 0; i<l.size(); i++){
          if(l.get(i)==n){ 
              l.remove(i);
               i--;
               System.out.println("Se ha eliminado");

          } 


       }
        System.out.println(l);



    }


    public static void remplazarpilas(){
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       Stack <Integer> pila1 = new Stack <Integer> ();
       Stack <Integer> pila2 = new Stack <Integer> ();

       //Apilamos los datos a la pila
       pila1.push(1);
       pila1.push(2);
       pila1.push(3);
       pila1.push(4);
       pila1.push(5);
       pila1.push(6);
       pila1.push(7);
       pila1.push(8);
       pila1.push(9);

         System.out.println(pila1);



        System.out.println("Indicame el Dato a remplazar:");
        int DatoR = Scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Indicame el nuevo dato:");
        int DatoN = Scan.nextInt();



       while(!pila1.empty()){
           int dato = pila1.pop();

          if(dato !=DatoR){
              pila2.push(dato);
          }else{    
              pila1.push(DatoN);

          }
       }

        while(!pila2.empty()){
            pila1.push(pila2.pop());

        }  

          System.out.println(pila1);   
    }


    public static void mezcla(){

        ArrayList <Persona> Lista1 = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        ArrayList <Persona> Lista2 = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        ArrayList <Persona> mostrarPersonas = new ArrayList<Persona>();


       //Añadimos los datos a la arrayList de Lista1

       Persona p1= new Persona("pol","Aguilar");
       Lista1.add(p1);

       Persona p2= new Persona("Roger","Carreras");
       Lista1.add(p2);

       Persona p3= new Persona("Nona","Ruiz");
       Lista1.add(p3); 

       //Añadimos los datos a la arrayList de Lista2
       Persona p4 = new Persona("Juan" , "Carlos");
       Lista2.add(p4);

       Persona p5 = new Persona("Aitor" , "Carreras");
       Lista2.add(p5);

       Persona p6 = new Persona("Nuria" , "Gomez");
       Lista2.add(p6);


       for(int x=0; x<Lista1.size(); x++){

           Persona per = Lista1.get(x);
           mostrarPersonas.add(per);
       }

     for(int y=0; y<Lista1.size(); y++){

           Persona per = Lista2.get(y);
           mostrarPersonas.add(per);
       }

     for(int x=0; x<mostrarPersonas.size(); x++){
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         System.out.println("Nombre: " + mostrarPersonas.get(x).getNombre());
         System.out.println("Apellido: " + mostrarPersonas.get(x).getApellidos());
     }  


    }

     public static void imprimeenteros(){

          ArrayList <Integer> enteros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);


           enteros.add(1);
           enteros.add(2);
           enteros.add(3);
           enteros.add(4);
           enteros.add(5);

          int dato;


          System.out.println("Indicame la Posicion que quieres comenzar a imprimir:");
          dato = Scan.nextInt();




          for(int i=dato; i>=0; i--){

              System.out.println(enteros.get(i));



          }



     }


     public static void apilar(){
        boolean salir = false;   
    while(!salir){    
       Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("1.- Alumno");
       System.out.println("2.- Profesor");
       System.out.println("3.- Mostrar Alumnos y profesores");

       int opcion = Scan.nextInt();

       Alumno alum = new Alumno();
       Profesor prof = new Profesor();

      switch(opcion){

          case 1:

           System.out.println("Nombre Alumno: ");
           String nombrealum = Scan.next() ;
           alum.setNombre(nombrealum);

           System.out.println("Edad Alumno: ");
           int edadalum = Scan.nextInt();
           alum.setEdad(edadalum);


           alumnos.push(alum);

           Alumno datosalumnos = (Alumno) alumnos.pop();
           profalum.push(datosalumnos);


          System.out.println("Se ha apilado correctamente.");  

           break;




          case 2:

              System.out.println("Nombre Profesor:");
              String nombreprof = Scan.next();
              prof.setNombre(nombreprof);

              System.out.println("Edad Profesor:");
              int edadprof = Scan.nextInt();
              prof.setEdad(edadprof);

              profesores.push(prof);


              Profesor datosprofesores = (Profesor) profesores.pop();
              profalum.push(datosprofesores); 


              System.out.println("Se ha apilado correctamente.");

              break;



          case 3:

                  for(int x = 0; x<profalum.size(); x++){

                      System.out.println("Nombre: " + profalum.get(x).getNombre());
                      System.out.println("Edad: " + profalum.get(x).getEdad());



                  }

          case 4: 

                salir = true;

                 break;

           }









      }

     }

     public static void productos(){

         String espacio="    ";
         String espacio1 ="        ";
         String espacio2 ="            ";

         Random ran = new Random();

         ArrayList <Productos> p = new ArrayList<Productos>();



         Productos Productos1 = new Productos("Producto1", 5, 2.6);
         p.add(Productos1);

         Productos Productos2 = new Productos("Producto2",8,3.5);
         p.add(Productos2);

         Productos Productos3 = new Productos("Producto3",2,5.4);
         p.add(Productos3);

         Productos Productos4 = new Productos("Producto4",10,9.5);
         p.add(Productos4);

         Productos Productos5 = new Productos("Producto5",3,4.5);
         p.add(Productos5);

         Productos Productos6 = new Productos("Producto6",1,7.2);
         p.add(Productos6);

         Productos Productos7 = new Productos("Producto7",7,20.5);
         p.add(Productos7);


         Productos Productos8 = new Productos("Producto8",10,8.5);
         p.add(Productos8);

         double preciototal;

         preciototal = Productos1.precioFinal() + Productos2.precioFinal() + Productos3.precioFinal() + Productos4.precioFinal() + Productos5.precioFinal() + Productos6.precioFinal() + Productos7.precioFinal() + Productos8.precioFinal();



        for(int x=0; x<p.size(); x++) {

         int randomIndex = ran.nextInt(p.size());
         System.out.println("Nombre" + "----"  + "Cantidad" +"----" +"Precio" +"----" + "----" + "Total") ;
         System.out.println(p.get(x).getNombres()+ espacio + p.get(randomIndex).getCantidad() + espacio1+  p.get(randomIndex).getPrecio()+ espacio2 + p.get(x).precioFinal());



        }
          System.out.println("Precio TOTAL: " + preciototal);

     }





 }
```

Comment: Hola, el computación la generación aleatoria es en realidad pseudoaleatoria, es un problema no resuelto. Si buscas una secuencia de números únicos, tendrías que ir generando números guardandolos en alguna estructura  e ir comprobando cada nuevo número generado con los existentes antes de guardarlo, puede complicar mucho tu problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es imprimir los productos en un orden pseudoaleatorio sin que se repitan, podés usar una lista auxiliar, usar random para seleccionar el elemento, y luego quitarlo de la lista para que no pueda ser elegido nuevamente.

```
ArrayList<Productos> aux = new ArrayList<Productos>(p);
int cantItems = aux.size();
for(int x=0; x < cantItems ; x++) {

     int randomIndex = ran.nextInt(aux.size());
     Productos productoRandom = aux.remove(randomIndex);
     System.out.println("Nombre" + "----"  + "Cantidad" +"----" +"Precio" +"----" + "----" + "Total") ;
     System.out.println(productoRandom.get(x).getNombres()+ espacio + productoRandom.getCantidad() + espacio1+  productoRandom.getPrecio()+ espacio2 + productoRandom.precioFinal());

    }
      System.out.println("Precio TOTAL: " + preciototal);
```

Gracias @JDev por la corrección en la cantidad de loops!

Comment: Ojo, con ese código al evaluar `x<aux.size();`si vas eliminando elementos en cada iteración la evaluación sera una unidad menos por lo que al final solo recorreras la mitad del array si es par o la mitad mas uno si es impar. Para evitarlo mejor almacenar la cantidad inicial en una variable y usar ese valor en el `for`

Comment: Por eso mismo, solo lo va a ejecutar 5 veces en vez de 10

Comment: Prque `x` aumenta en 1 tambien. cuando hayan transcurrido 5 iteraciones tendras `x=5` y `aux.size() = 5` y terminará el bucle.